# Difference between "are not yet" and "have not yet"

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect, linking-verbs

What is the meaning difference in below sentences using *Are not yet* and *have not yet*?

> a) “Our lungs ***have not yet*** fully developed and we cannot take further pollution through bursting of crackers,“
>
> b) “Our lungs ***are not yet*** fully developed and we cannot take further pollution through bursting of crackers,“

As per my knowledge the sentence (a) suggests an action/activity of the development of the lungs and sentence (b) gives an idea of the status/fact of lungs development.

Please help if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct. The difference between the sentences is that in sentence one *have* is an **auxiliary** and in the second sentence *are* is a **copular verb**.

This means that in the first sentence *developed* is **a lexical verb** while in the second one it is **an adjective**. The first sentence emphasises the action that has not yet been completed and the second sentence talks about the state of the lungs.